# Как вывести данные из двух таблиц в JSON?

Tags: java, spring, rest

подскажите как вывести данные из двух связанных таблиц в ответ метода? В частности по полю suppliers.

Есть таблица Product связанная с Suppliers отношением OneToMany.
Есть таблица Suppliers связанная с Product отношением @ManyToOne.

Что нужно: реализовать метод который выведет данные из двух таблиц, структура примерно следующая должна быть:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "productName": "Аспирин",
        "productCode": 124,
        "bareCode": 123456789,
        "produce": "БАЙЕР",
        "type": "Лекарства",
        "price": 432,
        "suppliers": [
           {
             "id": 1,
             "company": "ООО Компания № 1",
             "inn": "0123456789"
           },
           {
             "id": 2,
             "company": "ООО Компания № 2",
             "inn": "0123456785"
           }

       ]
    }...
   ]
```

Сценарий такой что productName == аспирин как на примере выше поставляют на рынок две компании. (один товар ко многим поставщикам, один и тот же товар могут возить несколько поставщиков)

Сейчас метод http://localhost:8080/api/product возвращает данные с пустым массивом по полю suppliers

пример ответа:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "productName": "Аспирин",
        "productCode": 124,
        "bareCode": 123456789,
        "produce": "БАЙЕР",
        "type": "Лекарства",
        "price": 432,
        "suppliers": []
    }...
]
```

Собственно вопрос как вывести данные по полю suppliers в виде массива объектов?
Таблица в БД заполнена корректно, см фото внизу описания. Правда создается еще одна дополнительная таблица product_entity_suppliers пока не понимаю почему.

Реализация следующая:

Entity Product

```
package com.example.product.entity;


import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_entity")
@Data
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "product_code")
    private Integer productCode;

    @Column(name = "bare_code")
    private Integer bareCode;

    @Column(name = "produce")
    private String produce;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Suppliers.class)
    private List<Suppliers> suppliers;

    public List<Suppliers> getSuppliers() {
        return suppliers;
    }

    public void setSuppliers(List<Suppliers> suppliers) {
        this.suppliers = suppliers;
    }
}
```

Entity Suppliers

```
package com.example.product.entity;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table(name = "suppliers")
@Data
public class Suppliers {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "company")
    private String company;

    @Column(name = "inn")
    private Long inn;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long productId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Product product;

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

repository

```
package com.example.product.repository;

import com.example.product.entity.Product;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {

    Product findByProductName(String productName);

    List<Product> findProductByProductNameContaining(String productProductName);


}
```

service

```
package com.example.product.service;

import com.example.product.dto.ProductDto;
import com.example.product.entity.Product;
import com.example.product.repository.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ProductService {
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ProductService(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    // Создание продукта

    public Product addProduct(Product product) {
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    // Получение продуктов
    

    public Iterable<Product> getAll() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    // Получение продукта

    public Product getOne(Long id) {
        Product product = productRepository.findById(id).get();
        return product;
    }

    // Обновление продукта

    public Product update(Long id, Product product) {
        product.setId(id);
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    // Удаление продукта

    public Long delete(Long id) {
        productRepository.deleteById(id);
        return id;
    }

    // Поисковые запросы

    public List<Product> getProductByProductName(String productName) {
        return productRepository.findProductByProductNameContaining(productName);
    }


}
```

controller

```
package com.example.product.controllers;


import com.example.product.entity.Product;
import com.example.product.service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/product")
public class ProductController {
    private final ProductService productService;

    public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
        this.productService = productService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity addProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        productService.addProduct(product);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(product);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity getAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.getAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity getOne(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.getOne(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity updateProduct(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Product product) {
        productService.update(id, product);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(product);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity deleteProduct(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.delete(id));
    }

    // *Поисковые запросы

    // Фильтр по наименованию товара

   
    @GetMapping(params = "productName")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> productByName(@RequestParam("productName") String productName) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.getProductByProductName(productName));
    }

    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правлю свой ответ.
У вас скорее всего стоит настройка `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`
из-за которой автоматически создается таблица product_entity_suppliers, которая отвечает за связь таблиц игнорируя, что у вас во второй таблице есть связь через колонку product_id.
Если в product_entity_suppliers добавить строки со связанными product_id и suppliers_id, то в ответе увидите нужный набор данных.

Если хотите обойтись без отдельной таблицы с двумя исходными таблицами, то код можно поменять на:
https://github.com/SpardaRus/stackOverflow_db

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_entity")
@Data
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "product_code")
    private Integer productCode;

    @Column(name = "bare_code")
    private Integer bareCode;

    private String produce;

    private String type;

    private Integer price;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="suppliers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="id")
    )
    private List<Suppliers> suppliers;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "suppliers")
@Data
public class Suppliers {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String company;

    private Long inn;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long productId;

}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Метод отрабатывает скриншот: https://ibb.co/X5QfRh1, в рекурсию не уходит, но в ответе поля "suppliers": [] - пустой массив.
Может где то я ошибся? Связь добавлена для таблиц, данные в таблице есть. 

как мне вывести в этот массив данные?
примерная структура для поля suppliers
скриншот: https://ibb.co/wBLMb3b

Comment: Мой измененный ответ не подошел?

Comment: Метод работает, но возвращает пустой массив по полю "suppliers": [ ]
Хотя по идее должен вывести данные из таблицы связанной.

Comment: @Сергей выше ссылка на гит https://github.com/SpardaRus/stackOverflow_db попробуйте посмотреть, сам запускал и все работает корректно, выводя массив "suppliers": [ ], если id корректно связать в бд

Comment: @Алексей Благодарю, с Вашей помощью разобрался, связь не так изначально построил. Все работает с тем кодом что прислали.